# Coldfusion Pagination - Fixed Number of Page Numbers

Tags: coldfusion, pagination, cfc

I'm using [dopefly's Pagination.cfc](http://www.dopefly.com/projects/pagination/) to create Pagination on a site I'm building, however I can't get it to react specifically how I want it to.

I'm trying to get it so it starts like this

```
*1* 2 3 4 ... x        
1 *2* 3 4 ... x        
1 2 *3* 4 ... x         
1 2 3 *4* ... x         
1 ... 4 *5* 6 7 ... x
```

So it will always display 4 in the middle, with the first and last pages showing at the end when appropriate.

However, at the moment it is going

```
*1* 2 3 4 ... x
1 *2* 3 4 5 ... x
1 2 *3* 4 5 6 ... x
1 2 3 4 *5* 6 7 ... x
1 2 3 4 5 *6* 7 8 ... x
1 ... 3 4 5 6 *7* 8 9 ... x
1 ... 4 5 6 7 *8* 9 10 ... x
```

So it keeps going until there is 8 that are displayed, then it will start keeping 7 in the middle, rather than staying with 4, then when we hit the 5th page displaying 4 in the middle at all times with the first/last at the end.

**e:** I've tried playing about with the `setNumericEndBufferCount()` and `setNumericDistanceFromCurrentPageVisible()` variables defined in the documentation, however my knowledge of cfc's and how they behave isn't expansive enough to modify the actual `cfc` (like [duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862368/coldfusion-pagination-fixed-number-of-page-numbers/13862878#13862878) suggested below).

Comment: So what have you tried? The [documentation](http://www.dopefly.com/projects/pagination/pagination_cfc_documentation.cfm) shows settings to handle this.

Comment: @PeterBoughton - It does indeed, but it still isn't working the way I want it to regardless of what settings I try modifying.

Comment: So ***what have you tried?*** - show us the code that you think should work. It can either be confirmed as a bug/lack of feature, or suggested how it should be adapted to work appropriately.

Comment: @PeterBoughton - Sorry, I've only tried modifying the default settings, as in `NumericDistanceFromCurrentPageVisible` and `setNumericEndBufferCount`, which controls how many display to begin with/how many show up, but it still doesn't act how I want it to behave. I don't know how to modify the `.cfc` directly to obtain what I want it do to.

Comment: Heh, just looked at the CFC code... :& it should just be some relatively simple maths, but is an effort following what's going on. :/

Comment: Yeah, I took one look past the default variables and was lost at how confusing it was. I'm thinking of removing the pagination all together and just using an endless jQuery style thing.

Comment: There's a way simpler one on GitHub - https://github.com/pmcelhaney/Paginator.cfc - I'd suggest extending that to work how you want rather than trying to comprehend/change the other. (Not a fan of endless scrolling things myself.)

Comment: More advanced, but still relatively simple: https://github.com/stevemo/pagination

Comment: @PeterBoughton - Working on the pmcelhaney one atm, seems to do the trick more so! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joshua,
Thanks for using my Pagination library! Sorry it's not acting exactly as you had hoped. Your issue looks similar to a feature request posted recently, requesting a [setFixedMaximumNumbersShown](http://paginationcfc.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.issue&issueid=528D04E8-95D1-4C79-00B755FED626EE78) option but with some sort of bouncy counting and some elasticity somewhat like Amazon's pagination, but as you noticed, it only grows as you page through your records. You can fix this yourself, but you will have to stretch your limits of CFC use a bit.

The solution is to create a component (let's call it `bouncyPagination.cfc`) that extends my component, `Pagination.cfc`. You will need to override at least one method to accomplish your task. You can read the [documentation on Extending Pagination.cfc](http://www.dopefly.com/projects/pagination/pagination_cfc_documentation.cfm#Section6) first, it may help. Your code will look something like this.

```
<cfcomponent extends="Pagination">
    <cffunction name="renderNumericLinksHTML">
        <!--- Your improved bouncy numeric links HTML generation here --->
        <!--- Start by copying & pasting code from the matching --->
        <!--- renderNumericLinksHTML method in Pagination.cfc --->
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Take a look at the code in `Pagination.cfc`, in the renderNumericLinksHTML function. Start yourself off by copying and pasting, then rewrite the way `BouncyPagination.cfc` writes those numeric links based on whatever logic you want. You can even add some methods to get and set the boundaries of your numbers, in your example, `4` was the magic number. I would imagine you would add something like this to your component.

```
<!--- Set your new parameter's default by overriding the init method --->
<cffunction name="init">
    <cfset variables.my.BouncyBounds = 4 />
    <return super.init() />
</cffunction>

<!--- Create getter/setter. Note the rendered=false is a flag to force HTML recomposition when a UI option changes. --->
<cffunction name="getBouncyBounds">
    <cfreturn variables.my.bouncyBounds />
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="setBouncyBounds">
    <cfargument name="_BouncyBounds" type="string" />
    <cfset variables.my.BouncyBounds = arguments._BouncyBounds/>
    <cfset variables.my.rendered = false />
</cffunction>
```

Your new `renderNumericLinksHTML` method would call `getBouncyBounds()` to programmatically change the boundaries of your newer bouncy pagination method.

I hope that helps you -- this is as far as I go without doing your homework for you. If you write something that works well for you, and you can share with a BSD license, send me the code and I will include it in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://www.dopefly.com/projects/pagination/pagination_cfc_documentation.cfm) it sounds like you could achieve this by using `NumericDistanceFromCurrentPageVisible`. The problem is that indicated how many links to use either side of the current link.  So you could set it to 2 and it would display 2 links either side of the current, i.e. groups of 5.  To achieve a group of 4 you'd have to display 1 link before and 2 links after (or vice versa)... or 3 links after or before if you're at the start or end of the list of links.

Suggest you delve into the CFC itself, see how it handles NumericDistanceFromCurrentPageVisible, and see if you could extend this to take 2 parameters for number of links to display before/after.  Or alternatively, modify it to use that parameter as a basis for how many links to display in total in a group.

Comment: I understand that the `.cfc` could be modified to do this, however I don't know how to extend the function to take 2 extra parameters, hence why I've posted a question here. Apologies if I wasn't clear enough, I will edit my question.